# VS2012 WCF / IIS Express 'Failed to register url / Cannot create a file when that file already exists.'

Tags: wcf, iis-express

I was doing some work earlier in WCF and I finally got it all working with SSL by following this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx . When I rebooted my PC, my services stopped working - the browser would just say 'connection reset'.

I spent a lot of time scratching my head and playing around, and now the service won't launch at all. I get the message in the title when I try to run it.

I'm at a total loss of what to do. I've tried deleting the config folder and it has recreated it, but I just get this error every time and I don't even know what it means.

Interestingly if I make a new project of the same type (WCF Service Application) it runs and works perfectly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps it's a permission thing (thinking of the failed to register url part of the message).  Have you tried running Visual Studio as an administrator?

Comment: Tried that, yes. In the end, I installed IIS and just deployed to that instead of express. It worked once I'd reconfigured everything for IIS.